# JavaFX loading image from variable path

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make a simple dice software which randomly generates a number between 1 and 6 and outputs an image of the dice in that state respectively.

I'm having issues grabbing the image path when using the `Image` object to generate an image. If I put a path in directly it works, but trying to use a variable gives me errors.

When I click the 'Randomise' button in the software, the following errors are printed:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1118)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:620)
    at dicegui.DiceGUI.lambda$start$0(DiceGUI.java:83)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1110)
    ... 49 more
```

This is the code that is sprouting the error:

```
        btnRand.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) ->
        {
            String imgPath = getImage();
            System.out.println("\"" + imgPath + "\"");
            Image img = new Image("\"" + imgPath + "\"");
            //Image img = new Image("img/2.png"); I WAS JUST USING THIS TO TEST
            grid.getChildren().add(new ImageView(img));
            randOutput.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
        });
```

This is my whole code. It is worth noting that I am using NetBeans.

```
package dicegui;


import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author josef
 */
public class DiceGUI extends Application
{
    public int rollDice()
    {
        int value;
        Random ran = new Random();

        value = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;

        return value;
    }

    public String getImage()
    {
        int value = rollDice() - 1;
        String imageLocation;

        String[] images = new String[6];
        images[0] = "img/1.png";
        images[1] = "img/2.png";
        images[2] = "img/3.png";
        images[3] = "img/4.png";
        images[4] = "img/5.png";
        images[5] = "img/6.png";

        imageLocation = images[value];

        return imageLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle("DiceGUI");

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));


        Button btnRand = new Button("Randomise");
        GridPane.setHalignment(btnRand, HPos.CENTER);
        grid.add(btnRand, 0, 0);

        Label randOutput = new Label("Not yet randomised");
        randOutput.setTextFill(Color.web("#CD2626"));
        GridPane.setHalignment(randOutput, HPos.CENTER);
        grid.add(randOutput, 0, 1);

        btnRand.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) ->
        {
            String imgPath = getImage();
            System.out.println("\"" + imgPath + "\"");
            Image img = new Image("\"" + imgPath + "\"");
            //Image img = new Image("img/2.png");
            grid.getChildren().add(new ImageView(img));
            randOutput.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
        });





        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The file structure is as follows:

[image: file structure]

Comment: Can you please share your file structure?

Comment: @SamuelP. apologies, I've edited the main post. I hope that's what you're looking for.

Note, that is also:
`C:\Users\name\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DiceGUI\src\img`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using double quotes at the start and end of your string, which produces an invalid filepath, e.g. `"img/5.png"`. The valid path is `img/5.png`

Just use `imgPath` to load the image:

```
Image img = new Image(imgPath);
```

Alternatively you can use the class loader to get the resources:

```
Image img = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + imgPath));
```

Comment: I tried denoting the file path without the quotes and it threw me an error. I can't remember specifically since I've found the alternative solution listed below, but nevertheless thanks for your support!

Answer (score -1):

*Note: While this solution does work, I have resorted to the solution posted above.*

I figured it out.

From what I understand, `ImageView` only works for URLs, so I had to convert the file path to a URL, like so:

```
public String getImage()
    {
        int value = rollDice() - 1;
        String imageLocation;
        String imageLocationReturn;

        String[] images = new String[6];
        images[0] = "src/img/1.png";
        images[1] = "src/img/2.png";
        images[2] = "src/img/3.png";
        images[3] = "src/img/4.png";
        images[4] = "src/img/5.png";
        images[5] = "src/img/6.png";

        imageLocation = images[value];

        File f = new File(imageLocation);
        imageLocationReturn = f.toURI().toString();

        return imageLocationReturn;
    }
```

Then in my `ActionEvent` I just needed:

```
btnRand.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) ->
        {
            String imgPath = getImage();
            Image img = new Image(imgPath);
            grid.getChildren().add(new ImageView(img));
        });
```

Comment: It doesn't only work with URLs; if the `String` has no scheme (e.g. `file:` or `https:`) then it interprets the path as relative to the _root of the classpath_. In typical Java projects the `src` folder is not _included_ in the classpath, but is the _root_ of the classpath. Same with the resources directory, if present.

Comment: So in this circumstance, what is the root directory? This is my first program using netbeans, normally I just write up in sublime text but since using javafx I found that really difficult, but the file infrastructure of netbeans projects confuses me.

Comment: I'm not sure about a "pure" Java project (whatever the IDE). I rarely don't use build tools, such as Maven or Gradle, where by default source files go in `src/main/java` and resources go in `src/main/resources`; those two directories would "be" the root of the classpath. I would expect the valid absolute path to be, for example, `"/img/1.png"` in your case. Your problem might be having the images in the sources directory? A lot of IDEs (and build tools) will ignore non-`*.java` files inside the sources directory. You might want to look up how to include resources in a NetBeans Java project.

Comment: In any case, using `new File("src/img/1.png").toURI().toString()` is incorrect. It may work in your IDE but it's very unlikely to work once you package your project in a JAR file (or some other deployment). Resources should not be thought of as files, even if they're usually represented that way.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from now and have amended my system. On build, the 'img' folder is found within the classpath, so this does work.